# Norm of a bounded linear functional as the reciprocal of the distance from zero to an hyperplane

Tags: analysis, functional-analysis

Let $(X,\|\;\|)$ be a normed vector space over $K$ and let $f\in B(X,K)$ (bounded linear functional) $(f\neq0$). Let $L=\{x\in X: f(x)=1\}$. I want to prove that:

$$
\|f\|=\frac{1}{d(0,L)}
$$

My attempt goes like this:

Since $f$ is bounded, is clear that $|f(x)|\le\|f\|\|x\|\;\;\forall x\in X$. So,
$$
1\le\|f\|\|x\|\;\forall x\in L
$$
and,
$$
\frac{1}{\|f\|}\le\|x\|\;\;\forall x\in L
$$
thus
$$
\frac{1}{\|f\|}\le\inf_{x\in L}(\|x\|)=\inf_{x\in L}(d(0,x))=d(0,L)
$$
so
$$
\|f\|\ge\frac{1}{d(0,L)}
$$
Any ideas for the other part would be appreciated since I couldn't figure out how to show that $\|f\|\|x\|\le 1\;\;\forall x\in L$

Answer (score 6, accepted):

By definition of $\Vert f \Vert$, for all $\epsilon >0$, one can find $x$ with $\Vert x \Vert=1$ and $$\vert f(x) \vert \ge \frac{\Vert f \Vert}{1+\epsilon}$$
Now take $y=\frac{x}{f(x)}$. You have $f(y)=1$, hence by definition of $d(0,L)$, $\Vert y \Vert \ge d(0,L)$ or $$1=\Vert x \Vert \ge \vert f(x) \vert d(0,L) \ge \frac{\Vert f \Vert}{1+\epsilon} d(0,L)$$

As this is true for all $\epsilon >0$, you finally get $$1 \ge \Vert f\Vert d(0,L)$$ as desired.

Comment: Ok, but I don't know how you get that $$|f(x)|\ge\frac{\|f\|}{1+\epsilon}$$, since from the definition of $\|f\|=\sup_{\|x\|=1}\|f(x)\|$ I can only get that $\forall\epsilon>0$ find $x$ with $\|x\|=1$ and $\|f\|-\epsilon\le|f(x)|\le \|f\|$

Comment: and taking the same $y$:
$$
1=\|x\|\ge |f(x)|d(0,L)\ge (\|f\|-\epsilon)d(0,L)=\|f\|d(0,L)-\epsilon d(0,L)\;\;\forall \epsilon>0
$$

Comment: Take in your inequality $\epsilon^\prime=\frac{\epsilon}{1+\epsilon} \Vert f \Vert $ and you'll get my inequality. Anyhow as you get $1 \ge \Vert f \Vert d(0,L)-\epsilon d(0,L)$ for all $\epsilon$, you also conclude to $1 \ge \Vert f \Vert d(0,L)$

Comment: Oh yes, I see it now. Thank you!